# Unexpected token '<' in React Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to implement a language context in a React App, however when I try to pass some elements into the value prop, it won't work.

The error is: Unexepect token in line 2:2 (i.e.). But the tags are well closed. Am I missing something in value which is absolutely required?

```
const LanguageProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <LanguageContext.Provider value={{
    setLanguage,
    translations
  }}
  >
    {children}
  </LanguageContext.Provider>
);
```

setLanguage comes from:

`const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en_US');`

and translations equals to an object of strings:

```
const translations = {
    en_US: {
      settings: {
        menu: 'Main Menu',
        screen: 'Screen'
      }
    },
    es_MX: {
      settings: {
        menu: 'Menú Principal',
        screen: 'Pantalla'
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you try wrapping your {children} in a element, like <>{children}</> or a div

Comment: Tried both, but I got the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags are okay, you just need to move `setLanguage` into `LanguageProvider`.

```
const LanguageProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en_US");

    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider
            value={{
            setLanguage,
            translations
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

I have a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-dw6uy?file=/src/App.js:329-597) you can try.